Is there a shielding difference from switching terminals of an MLCC capacitor?
For electrolytic capacitors, the capacitor has only one working polarity (or it
usually will get damaged if reversed).
For film capacitors, the outermost metal layers ("left" and "right") usually connect
to the same terminal, so polarity can be important for shielding.
What about MLCC capacitors?  I'm using this one in a current project
and wondering if it might have its outermost metal/conductor layers going to the same terminal.
There's no polarity indication in the datasheet, so how do normal MLCC manufacturing
processes wire their outermost metal layers?  Do they keep it completely symmetric
(completely symmetric would wire the two outermost metal sides to opposite terminals,
not to the same terminal, though this is not optimum shielding)?

I'm curious what are you shielding, that 10 mm^2 will make a difference?

As long as the two electrodes are very tightly layered internally (they are), they appear "as one" for EMI purposes in the far field perspective. So there is no relevant difference in shielding function.
The layering in MLCCs is so tight that anything that is outside of its package can be considered to be in the far field.

I care more about the near-field 60 Hz.

@bobuhito That makes the near field slightly further only. Anything that is "far" relative to the size of the capacitor pads (~1mm) will see the common mode potential predominantly. And this is again irrespective of the polarity. I guess a relevant case might be a high impedance trace going directly beneath the cap. That would couple more to the outer electrode, but its capacitance to this electrode would be wayyy below pF, so still it is a really marginal case.
